# Can I amend the properties of a column in a table after the fact

Tags: mysql

I have a Timestamp columnn in a MySQL table. The default value of this column is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, I want to make the **ON UPDATE** property of this column also equal to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` without having to drop and re-add the column, as this would cause me to lose all of the data.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ought to be able to do this successfully with an `ALTER` statement:

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable
  MODIFY the_timestamp_column TIMESTAMP
     DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

It works correctly in my quick testing.